# Fixing FTBFS packages

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to 'cmake' for a program, but I get errors. On the web I found that my problems can be to solve by the patch: https://github.com/mati75/Kadu/commit/05afae19d4ff347f498aac8a4d8aff7c42b4e6cc
How to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure that the patch file is for the exact same revision of the source that you have.

Then change to the root dir of the source tree.

Then run the `patch` command and pipe in the patch file as input, for example the normal command is:

```
patch < 730923.patch
```

Note: the patch file generated in this case has an added directory level at the start: notice how the files begin with a/... and b/... - this is a relatively common convention in some tools that generate patch files.  Assuming the patch tool doesn't recognise this convention you can tell it to ignore the first path level like so:

```
patch -p1 < 730923.patch
```